# How do I implement access control permissions on Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

We store user permissions in claims.

Here's how the claim of a enterprise customer looks like:

```
{"roles": ["enterprise"]}
```

Then, in the rules of Firebase Storage, we try to check whether a customer is enterprise before they are granted access to some files:

```
function isEnterprise() {
  return (request.auth.token.roles) && ("enterprise" in request.auth.token.roles);
}
```

Then, when the user attempts to retrieve the Download URL of a file from the web using `getDownloadURL`, Firebase throw a permissions error.

Could you please provide a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it with this:

```
function isEnterprise() {
  return request.auth.token.roles.hasAny(['enterprise']);
}
```